# How to run a search and replace command without cursor moving in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

In Vim, when I run a substitution command like

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

it replaces all occurrences of `foo` with `bar` in the entire buffer. When it completes, the cursor moves to the last location where `foo` was replaced with `bar`.

How can I run `:%s/foo/bar/g` without having the cursor leave its original location where it was before the substitution command was issued?

Is there some option I can set in the `.vimrc` file?

Comment: Not sure about doing it without moving the cursor, but you can move it back by hitting single-quote twice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> after the replace to get back to the previous location.

Answer (score 39):

When the `:substitute` command is run, prior to any replacements being
carried out, the current position of the cursor is stored in the jump
list (see `:help jumplist`).

In order to return to the position before the latest jump, one can use
the ``` `` ``` or `''` Normal-mode commands. The former
jumps exactly to the stored position; the latter jumps to the first
non-whitespace character on the line the stored position belongs to.

It is possible to both invoke a substitution command and move
the cursor back afterwards, at once, by issuing the command

```
:%s/pat/str/g|norm!``
```

or, if jumping to the containing line is sufficient, by using
the command

```
:%s/pat/str/g|''
```

It is not necessary to preface `''` with `norm!` in the latter
command, because the `''` address is allowed by the range syntax
of Ex commands and refers to the same line the Normal-mode
command `''` jumps to (see `:help :range`); both just look into
the contents of the `'` psudo-mark.

Comment: Nice try. But not elegant. shoud use `Ctrl-o`.

Comment: @mattn:  According to what criterion using `Ctrl`+`O` is elegant, while `\`\`` is not?  The latter command is not longer than the former one in terms of keystrokes; both of them lead to the same cursor movement in this case.  Why do you find pressing `\`\`` (instead of `Ctrl`+`O`) inelegant?

Comment: It's simple answer. longer than c-o. And your command update jumplist. If I use your way, I'll use g`. :)

Comment: Ah, I mistaken. I'll use keepjumps.

Comment: @mattn:  Excuse me?  `\`\`` is longer than `Ctrl`+`O`?!  Also, `Ctrl`+`O` updates the jump list too!  (See `:help jumplist` or just try yourself.)  So `\`\`` and `Ctrl`+`O` are apace of each other with regard to both modifying the jump list and the number of keys to press.  According to these criteria one command does not excel the other.  Do you still consider one of them more elegant?  If so, for what reason?

Comment: @ib. `and` @mattn I think it is mostly a matter of taste. To me \`\` trumps <C-o> (easier to type, expresses register use, and logically connects to `:''`, `:g//copy ''` and stuff. I don't no who downvoted this answer, but I certainly think a disagreement of taste shouldn't be reason for downvoting.

Comment: I beleaved that <c-o> accept two or more commands like replacements like ':%s/a/b/g|%s/c/d/g' with go back to original cursor position. but not. 
Hmm, It's same advantage.

Answer (score 3):

It's old, but for anyone coming across this question, I wanted to share my solution since it will work correctly even if nothing is substituted:

```
:exe 'norm m`' | %s/pattern/substitution/eg | norm g``
```

`exe` is needed since `norm` treats the bar as an argument.